# Regular expression encoded wrongly in another server

Tags: c#, iis, razor

I have this regular expression in model

```
[RegularExpression("^([^/\\*?:\"<>|]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Please do not use the following characters: \\/:*?\"<>|")]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Looking at the websites' html in browser:

in our live server:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please do not use the following characters: \/:*?&quot;&lt;&gt;|" data-val-regex-pattern="^([^/\*?:&quot;&lt;&gt;|]*)$" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="Foo">
```

and in our staging server:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-regex="Please do not use the following characters: \/:*?"<>|" data-val-regex-pattern="^([^/\*?:"<>|]*)$" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="Foo">
```

In our staging server, the regex works perfectly. How come in our live server the regex was encoded?

The user inputs last name but it cannot be accepted because the letters *q,u,o,t,l,g* became part of the regex validation.
The files deployed in staging and live servers are completely similar.

Is there a setting in IIS or in the server that might changed the encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try [Unicode escapes](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/actionscript/excerpts/as3-cookbook/appendix.html)?

You Regex should look something like

```
[RegularExpression("^([^/\\*?:\\u0022\\u003c\\u003e|]*)$", ....
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! after investigating this issue, I found out that a windows update caused the error. But I cannot trace which update it is. Thinking that eventually this update will cause error in the future, I decided to modify the code with your suggestion and deploy again. Thanks!